# Iterating bidimensional array/list with only one for (Python)

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

Instead of doing this:

```
for x in range(500):
    for y in range(300):
        print x,y
```

How can i do something like this?

```
for x,y in range(500),range(300):
    print x,y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product
for x, y in product(range(500), range(300)):
    print x, y
```

Answer (score 2):

## Using list comprehension:

```
pairs = [ (i,j) for i in range(300) for j in range(300) ]
print pairs
```

This is the test I have run:

```
print [ (i,j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3) ]
```

output

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

## Using itertools' product

```
print [ (i,j) for i, j in itertools.product(range(300), range(300))]
```

Comment: doesn't zip only work for lists with the same size? Also I prefer it being in the format i said because I need to do a lot of stuff there and list comprehension is a little bit limited since i can only put one line of code.

Comment: Yeah, I changed my answer, since `zip` doesn't do what you asked.